# Android relative layout alignment not working

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

in my case preview is showing properly. but run in real device items not placing as I expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
    app:fabSize="mini"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the output of real device.
[image: output]

Comment: Is this an activity's layout?

Comment: please click the output button end of my post

Comment: I did. I'm asking if this is the activity's layout or just an include part of the activity.

Comment: Do you believe, if I say that it works on my device? What's your device version? I had to download `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` on dependences, to build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Framelayout, which will be your new root layout. Inside it place your  FloatingActionButton and position it using `android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"`.You can also apply margins using `android:layout_marginBottom="xdp"` like you already do.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `CoordinatorLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
    app:fabSize="mini"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, need to do run **Clean project** and **Rebuild project**, because your code is correct.